# ISRC Matching Criteria for 7 digital and rovi

Tags: database, 7digital

mapping of a track record in 7digital and Rovi as multiple tracks have the same ISRC code ?
Pls suggest a way to map the track records.

If you have any knowledge and experience in this regard(7digital, Rovi, music database) kindly comment and i'll try to explain my problem in further details if i haven't made myself clear now.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're concerned about duplicates on either side? As far as the labels are concerned, same ISRC equals same song, though possibly from a different album (single vs original vs compilation). Still, it should be the same audio recording.

Comment: yes...they are from diff albums...any solution in mind to come up with a unique track record that is correct as far as the album is concerned ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there isn't one that's universal that the labels recognize. I'm afraid your only option would be MusicBrainz IDs, but there's no good mapping. EchoNest provides one, but they've been bought and are likely to choose soon.